# UIKit Swift: Shadow glitch, context menu

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, contextmenu

[I have a rectangle with a shadow and a context menu. When I close this context menu the shadow of the rectangle appears with a delay (~0.5 seconds). Both the shadow of the complete rectangle as well the shadow of the inner elements. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmrZz.gif)

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, contextMenuConfigurationForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
    
    if collectionView == foodOnTheShelf {
        
        let config = UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil) { _ in

            let edit = UIAction(title: "Изменить", image: UIImage(systemName: "pencil"), identifier: nil, discoverabilityTitle: nil, state: .off) { _ in
                self.alert.showAlert(viewController: self,
                                     image:  UIImage(named: test[indexPath.row].name)!,
                                     food: test[indexPath.row],
                                     picker: self.picker,
                                     consumePicker: self.consumePicker,
                                     unit: self.unit,
                                     currentWeigt: test[indexPath.row].weight,
                                     currentProductDate: test[indexPath.row].productionDate,
                                     currentExperationDate: test[indexPath.row].expirationDate,
                                     searchController: nil)
            }
            
            let delete = UIAction(title: "Удалить", image: UIImage(systemName: "trash"), attributes: .destructive) { _ in
                test.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                self.viewDidAppear(true)
            }
            return UIMenu(title: "", image: nil, identifier: nil, options: UIMenu.Options.displayInline , children: [edit, delete])
        }
        return config
    }
 return nil
    

}
```

Comment: Unrelated but you call yourself `self.viewDidAppear(true)`?

Comment: I'm just updating the collectionView here, I tried to remove it completely, it did not affect the result in any way.

Comment: `override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        foodOnTheShelf.reloadData()
        view.reloadInputViews()
    }`

Comment: It's just that you shouldn't call `viewDidAppear()`, `viewDidLoad()` etc, yourself. Btw, it should call `super.viewDidAppear(animated)`, and that `super` call might trigger other stuff, instead add a method `func reload()` where you reeload tableView & inputView (why reload inputView?).

Comment: Thank you for your help, I did just that, but unfortunately it did not solve the problem

Comment: That's why I said it is (might be) unrelated, but it could be lead to issues later.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69323482/8616676) you could add a shadow to a platter transition view, which is a temporary view shown after a context menu interraction ended.

The problem is that this transition view is a private class (`_UIContextMenuPlatterTransitionView`), so your App will be rejected if you use it.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willEndContextMenuInteraction configuration: UIContextMenuConfiguration, animator: UIContextMenuInteractionAnimating?) {
    guard let platter = platterTransitionView() else { return }
    addShadow(to: platter.layer) // add a shadow the same way you do for your cells
}

private func platterTransitionView() -> UIView? {
    guard let container = self.view.window?.subviews.filter({ type(of: $0) == NSClassFromString("_UIContextMenuContainerView") }).first else { return nil }
    return container.subviews.filter({ type(of: $0) == NSClassFromString("_UIContextMenuPlatterTransitionView") }).first
}
```

You could also try to access the transition view without checking its class, but this way is not safe/dynamic:

```
let platter = self.view.window?.subviews[2].subviews[1]
```